# How do I get more information with `npm run test`?

Tags: javascript, npm, jestjs

I am running `npm run test` with Jest and am receiving very little information in the CLI:

```
Test Suites: 1 failed, 19 passed, 20 total
Tests:       238 passed, 238 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        742.958 s
Ran all test suites.
```

`jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  roots: ['<rootDir>/test'],
  testMatch: ['**/*.test.ts'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest'
  }
};
```

`package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
  },
```

How can I obtain more information? For example, information about which suite failed or a table of all the tests for each suite.

Comment: It would've been more helpful to add your jest config and which command you are running wiht `npm run test`, I mean the one you have in `package.json`'s `scripts:test`

Comment: Scroll up? Any errors usually appear above that summary. The fact that you have a failing _suite_ but no failing _tests_ suggests it failed to run entirely, maybe you have a suite with no tests but then Jest _would_ tell you about it.

Comment: I've added more information. There are so many tests, I can only scroll up so far. It'd be better to have a more detailed level of reference at the bottom too.

Comment: So to put it another way: you _do_ have more information with `npm run test`? Are in fact receiving substantially more than the five lines of _"very little information"_ you show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `npm run test` with `jest` will not offer individual suite success reporting, and will offer the answer like this:

```
 RUNS  example-Stack.test.ts
 RUNS  example-Stack.test.ts
 RUNS  example-Stack.test.ts
 PASS  example-Stack.test.ts

Test Suites: 1 failed, 19 passed, 20 total
Tests:       238 passed, 238 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        742.958 s
Ran all test suites.
```

To obtain the individual test information for multiple suites, use `jest --verbose` in the scripts file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --verbose",
  },
```

This will show information about each test like you would experience running an individual test file.